# How to set a quarterly goal for a novice back-end web developer

Tags: software-industry, career-development

I am a back-end web developer who has just a year of experience, and I need to submit a quarterly goal to my company. I want to improve my Ruby on Rails skill, but I don't know how to make it a measurable goal. What would be a typical goal for a novice web developer who wants to improve their programming language?

Comment: There are so many things one can improve about any technology. Which areas do you want to improve? Once you understand that, add the information to the question, and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 4):

**I had to do this a week ago**

My company uses Angular, which is a framework I have no experience with, but as a full stack developer will need to learn relatively quickly. One of my quarterlies is to learn that framework to a semi-useful level. Here is what was documented as measurable:

- Complete Udemy course on Angular 10
- Can own angular tickets worth than 3 story points with limited direction

Would that do?

Answer (score 1):

Use SMART goals. This is a fairly standard way in business to talk about career goals. SMART is an acronym that stands for Specific, Measurable, Achievable, Relevant and Time-Bound. Notice that the M is what you are now looking for. Searching for SMART goals for software development will give you loads of resources on how to structure this. One nice example I encountered is [this one](https://medium.com/@adamtalcott/how-to-write-software-engineering-goals-d05c0597efd0), which uses for example the following as a *bad* goal formulation:

> Get better at deep learning

This is what you describe in your question. However, they also provide a good reformulation of the goal:

> By August 2018, write an article walking through an example of using Create ML with Xcode 10 to classify images of vehicles

This makes the goal quantifiable and will allow for your manager to actually see if you've achieved this goal.